# Can react.js can improve loading time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My website has a large no of images, can react.js can improves the loading time of website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a server with a large no of images. When your website loads those images need to be transferred from your server to the users browser. React will not help with this. React is:

> A JAVASCRIPT LIBRARY FOR BUILDING USER INTERFACES

There are ways to reduce loading times, such as reducing the size of images so that there is less data to transfer.
Google is always a good place to search for information like this.
Also try https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/ to seeing what is causing the issues with your page load time and what you can do about it.